# Update values for a UILabel placed in a UITableViews Section Header

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like for my section header to display the sum of the values in my rows.
I therefore implement the:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

delegate function and place a UILabel in the custom view I build here.

If this were a UITableViewCell I would build the cell if it did not exist, then update it, or if it exists - only update it.

I don't know which "pattern" to use to update my Section Header.
Either there is a "right way" build into the UITableView, but I can't seem to find an "updateSectionHeaderForSection" and call this only when I change the value of a row.

**What puzzles me is how the UITableView deals with headers, does it call `viewForHeadersInSection` only once on `reloadData`/instantiation or does it call it all the time, i.e. does it instantiate the view repeatedly when scrolling if I place this code in the viewController?:**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        UIImageView *shadow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.png"]];

}
```

**And how do I force the section header to update the view, like calling updateRowsAtIndexPaths, when I have changed the value it should display?**

I can't seem to find Apples take on this in the UITableView Programming Guide.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a similar thing recently, the way I did it was to draw a custom view in `viewForHeaderInSection`. This view contained a number of different components and for the label that I wanted to show the total in I gave it a tag

```
detailLabel.tag=100001;
```

Then, whenever I wanted to update the total I retrieve the associated view

```
UILabel *total = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:100001];
```

And update it to the value I wanted:

```
total.text = @"1234";
```

Comment: Hi Liam and thanks. I found the delegate methods that gets called following a [tableView endUpdates], one of them is tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: luckily the code getting executed when I need to update the total is incased in begin/endUpdates so in there I did as you suggest above:)